# Multiple domain with one database

Tags: multisite, database

I have multiple domain (Multiple domain + subdomain as well) for the different countries and for the different states of it. Now i want to run all the domain from one signle database, all the domain should have similar user id and password, If one user register from one domain it should update in all domain. If user/admin post blog in one domain it will update in all the domains.

The domains i have is like
abc.com (Currently running with one database)
nyc.abc.com
nj.abc.com
def.com
abc.co.uk
def.co.uk

If any change in one domain happen than it should change in all the domain,

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: It depends how you code. connect single db to all domain and call from that single table to all domain.